# Debian based arm SBC can not use bluetooth

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bluetooth, bluez

I have arm64 SBC with Debian 11 installed on it. As a communication I need to use bluetooth, for which sparkfun WPEQ-261ACNI(BT) was provided. it uses qualcomm chip on it and Debian 11 detect the wifi part of it, but bluetooth is not usable.

From what I was able to understand `firmware-atheros` only provides **wifi** connection.

When checking with `lsusb` I am getting :

`Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications QCA61x4 Bluetooth 4.0`

I have installed `firmware-atheros` and `firmware-realtek`, with all the `linux-firmware` packages and wifi works fine, but `bluetoothctl scan on`  return error with :

`No default controller available`

here is the output of
`dmesg|grep -iE 'firm|blue'`

```
[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.0 detected in firmware.
[   54.129618] imx-sdma 30bd0000.sdma: loaded firmware 4.5
[   58.679019] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 90eebefb
[  793.750879] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  793.751236] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  793.751788] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  793.751822] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  793.752239] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 3448.334457] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 3448.334525] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

additionally I thought this might be helpful as well:

`dmesg |grep -iE -C3 'QCA61'` with the out put of :

```
[   56.729063] cfg80211: loaded regulatory.db is malformed or signature is missing/invalid
[   58.031450] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[   58.033508] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq legacy oper_irq_mode 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   58.675133] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 168c:3363
[   58.675167] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   58.679019] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 90eebefb
[   58.920196] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 318825bf
```

I have also tried installing all the bluez software to the device and but nothing happens.

Any help will be appreciated